# How to fixed right column in jQuery datatable?

Tags: html, jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery Datatable to design a grid and below I am using the same example given in Datatables.net.

```html
<table id="example" class="stripe row-border order-column" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>Extn.</th>
      <th>E-mail</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger</td>
      <td>Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>5421</td>
      <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    proccessing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    scrollY: "300px",
    scrollX: true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging: false,
    fixedColumns: {
      left: 0,
      right: 1
    }
  });
});
```

My requirement is to freeze right side column but it is not working in my side. Its always freezing left side column whatever I use left or right in `fixedColumns`.

If anyone having any idea to fix this then it will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add the [datatables.net-fixedcolumns](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/) extension? https://jsfiddle.net/fq5k3rzL/

Comment: Have a look at https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html. You have to add https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/4.0.0/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js

Comment: Sorry, but I have already added fixedcolumns js file.

Comment: I am unable to recreate your problem. However, just to note, your example as shown in the question does not run, because it uses `serverSide: true` but there is no JSON data source provided. So, when I comment our that option, your code works as expected (the right hand column is fixed).

Comment: Please provide a [mre].